# Prevent navigator.getCurrentPosition coordinates from being altered

Tags: javascript, security, navigator

My Web app uses JavaScript's navigator.getCurrentPosition method to determine a user's location. My understanding is that JS can pinpoint the user's location to a much greater degree of accuracy than can be done on the server side.

Having said that, I know that users can modify the coordinates on the client side. I would like to prevent them from being altered if possible or at least validate the integrity of the values on the backend, using PHP. Any suggestions?

Thanks, 
Cody

Comment: The first part of your question ("*I would like to prevent them from being altered if possible*") can't be done. You're basically asking "how can the client be trusted?" -- it can't. The second part of your question ("*validate the integrity of the values on the backend*") might be possible if you simply want to verify that values at rest haven't been altered. If you want to know if new, incoming values are trustworthy, you're back to problem #1.

Comment: You could do a simple check to see if the user-reported location matches the geographic locale for the user's IP address: e.g., the client says it's at 50 Main Street, San Francisco, but its IP address is from France. However, this would give false negatives (or positives) if the user is using a proxy.